# Error: HDL-Complier-661 Non-net port cannot be mode of input

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to develop a Verilog code for right shifting as a part of Floating Point ALU. I'm getting the following error in line 7:

**Error: HDL-Complier-661 .... Non net port cannot be mode of input**

Please tell me what my error is and provide me with corrected code.

[image]

```
        `timescale 1ns / 1ps



    module right_shifter(small_mant, shift_amt, shifted_mant);

    input [3:0] small_mant; 
    input [2:0] shift_amt; 
    output [5:0] shifted_mant; 
    reg [3:0] small_mant;
    reg [5:0] shifted_mant;




    always@(small_mant or shift_amt)
    case (shift_amt)
    3'b000: shifted_mant <= {2'b01, small_mant[3:0]};
    3'b001: shifted_mant <= {3'b001, small_mant[3:1]};
    3'b010: shifted_mant <= {4'b0001, small_mant[3:2]};
    3'b011: shifted_mant <= {5'b00001, small_mant[3]};
    3'b100: shifted_mant <= 6'b000001;
    default: shifted_mant <= 6'b000000;
    endcase

    endmodule
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Verilog does not allow `input` ports declared as a variable with a data type (SystemVerilog does).You can remove that line. I also suggest using a simpler form of port declarations that only mentions each port name once instead of up to three times (called ANSI style in the IEEE LRM)

```
module right_shifter(
    input [3:0] small_mant,
    input [2:0] shift_amt,
    output reg [5:0] shifted_mant
);
```

Comment: This worked . Note that we have to use comas, instead if semicolons.                               `module right_shifter(
    input [3:0] small_mant,
    input [2:0] shift_amt,
    output reg [5:0] shifted_mant
);`

Answer (score 2):

You've declared your port as `input [3:0] small_mant;` - this means you are declaring an input to the module, which must be of a net type (a.k.a. a `wire`).

However you then re-declare your input port as `reg [3:0] small_mant;` which is a variable data type (`reg`), and therefore not a net type.

You cannot, and in fact never need to, declare an input as a `reg`, so simply remove that line.

Answer (score 0):

The corrected code :-

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

//Module: Shifts a given numner to the right by an amount (shift_amt)

module right_shifter(
    input [3:0] small_mant,
    input [2:0] shift_amt,
    output reg [5:0] shifted_mant
);


always@(small_mant or shift_amt)
case (shift_amt)
3'b000: shifted_mant <= {2'b01, small_mant[3:0]};
3'b001: shifted_mant <= {3'b001, small_mant[3:1]};
3'b010: shifted_mant <= {4'b0001, small_mant[3:2]};
3'b011: shifted_mant <= {5'b00001, small_mant[3]};
3'b100: shifted_mant <= 6'b000001;
default: shifted_mant <= 6'b000000;
endcase

endmodule
```